# Publishing to web from Shotwell in XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, shotwell, online-accounts

There are similar questions on this site  but none of them answers mine. I have Xubuntu 13.10 with Shotwell installed from Ubuntu repository. I also installed "gnome online accounts" and "signon" but still can't publish to any website from shotwell.

When I click on the "publish" icon, a dialog appears with a few choices like Piwigo, Tumblr, etc but none of them works. Is there anything else I have to install? Thanks.

Update: I tried to install shotwell from PPA but I got this error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/shotwell/ui/collection.ui', which is also in package shotwell-common 0.15.0-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you set up your Tumblr etc accounts in the accounts settings? Itmay be called Online Accounts.

Comment: There is no such option in online accounts. The only ones are for Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Comment: Errr... it gots 'Flickr'.... There is [this](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/share-upload.html) help page, that mentions Picasa and Flickr, but no Tumblr.

Comment: Thanks. But there is a Tumblr plugin in the list of plugins of shotwell (the application itself).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found no solution on the web. I thought it was impossible to publish on Picasa with Shotwell in Xubuntu, but I eventually found a very simple solution for me so I post it here for others.

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and I had Shotwell 18.0 installed from the official repository. When I clicked on the "publish" icon in Shotwell in order to publish on Picasa, a dialog appeared with one only choice : Piwigo. When trying to add another choice the windows disappeared without telling anything.

The solution that worked for me :

1. from the software library I installed the "ubuntu system settings online accounts"
2. in the terminal I installed the last stable version of Shotwell:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install shotwell
   ```

Now I have Shotwell version 0.20.2, and when I try to publish a photo, the dialog gives more choices : Piwigo, Picasa, Flickr, Facebook

When I chose Picasa, I was able to login with my usual login and password and it works. So I'm relieved I can use Picasa again.